# airdroid like app in wp8

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, windows-phone-8

We want to create a http server on wp8 that manages the phone files.After that we want the phone to connect to an external webservice to give the internal IP address that the service is being run at.

1.Can we create a http server on wp8 that can do that?

2.Can we create the external webservice with asp.net mvc web api running on localhost(IIS)?

After getting the IP address we want to  generate an url that inserted in a pc browser can establish a connection between the phone and pc. In pc browser page we want to be able to make requests to the http server on wp8 (airdroid like app).

Can this be done, considering the security ,in wp8?

Any documentation on any  of these questions is welcomed.

What i found untill now is that a connection between wp8 and pc can be done as this app shows http://wp8webserver.codeplex.com/

Comment: you might be able to listen on port 80, but you surely cannot access the local file system with an app distributed through the store.

Comment: if by access you mean read can i ask why? I don't want to access the system files,i want to read files like music/pictures etc

Comment: Ah, different story. With ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_* capablites, you can access those, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206936.aspx#BKMK_Softwarecapabilities and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509.aspx#BKMK_CAPABILITIESelement